# How to get different chapter titles in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, preamble

How do I get different chapter titles in `TOC`, e.g. "`Chapter`" for the first few chapters and "`Appendix`" for the last?

This is a part of my `preamble` and my main document:

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\addto\captionsdanish{
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\chaptername{Kapitel}
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse} 
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendiks}
}

\appendix

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\fontfamily{georgia}\bf\Huge\color{black}}{Appendiks \thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\filright\fontfamily{georgia}\Huge\bf}[\vspace{0.1mm}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}


Document:

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{First appendix}

\end{appendices}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on the site please post a full (but minimal) self contained example that others can test as is. As your question is now we cannot help as the answer depends on the document class and preamble you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you should use the `\appendix` command before your appendices. Note that it will affect each `\chapter{}` you will use after it.

`\appendix` will change "Kapitel" to "Anhang". If you want to have "Appendix" instead you should give the following command in your preamble, where `*appendix name*` is the word you want to have:

`\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{*appendix name*}}`

P.S.: I assumed that your document is in German and did some attempts. Please note that I'm not German, so there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `tocloft` and `appendix` packages. The following works with English names but the packages allow you to use any names you wish; read the documentation.

```
% tocnameprob.tex  % put Chapter/Appendix before the number
\documentclass{book} % or any other class that provides \chapter
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter } % put Chapter before ToC Chapter entries
\newlength{\tocl}% a scratch lenght
\settowidth{\tocl}{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}% extra space for Chapter
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\tocl}% add the extra space
\usepackage[titletoc]% Option to put Appendix (\appendixname) before ToC Appendix entries
           {appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{one}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[3]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{}} % nullify Chapter
\addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{-\tocl}} % delete space for Chapter
\chapter{Appone}  % first Appendix
\lipsum[5]
\section{appone}
\lipsum[6]
% and more appendices
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

There may be more efficiant ways to accomplish this, but it works.